# Run ASP.NET Core as Portable Client Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have .Net Core Application. I have to install the application as a Software Project on clients machines, because data (bio-metric, Identity Information etc..)  being sensitive and not allowed to be connected to Web. 
Data is Quarterly exported, verified and then given to WEB agencies under various security policies.

Is there any way to run the application as Portable Self Hosted. I have to run the application in various clients (more than 3000) computer systems.

About 40% systems are Windows 7 and rest 60% are Windows 8,8.1 and 10.
Which framework at least required on client to run the application?

How to create a portable setup that don't require any Internet and other dependencies, so as to provide in DVD or portable form ?

Answer (score 1):

[Self-contained deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd) is for you.

.NET Core 1.0 is supported [on Win7 SP1 and above](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md#net-core-10---supported-os-versions)

`dotnet publish` will create separate distrib folders for each SDK/platform which will contain everything to run, without any additional download/install (unless you use something that should be installed, like SQL Server).

Comment: Doest it support SQLCe 4 ?

Comment: SQL CE need "full" .NET Framework 3.5 / 4 ([see System Requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876)), so this framework must be installed on target machines.